# MASM error Unknown relocation type (1) with 16b code

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, x86-16, masm32

I am good with M68000 but X86 is diffficult for me. I am trying to assemble this simple program with MASM

```
.MODEL SMALL
.data?
  ONE  dB ?
  TWO  dB ?
  stack db  100 dup(?)

.data
  MSG  db 13,10, 'Enter deree of polynomials:  $'
  MSG2 db 13,10, 'Enter coefficient of x^ $' 
  MSG3 db 13,10, 'The polynomial created is: $'
  MSG4 db 13,10, 'The first derivative is: $'
  STR1 db  255 DUP('$')

.code

_start:

            mov ax, offset MSG
            mov ds, ax  

end _start
```

and I keep getting the error
Unknown relocation type (1) for symbol MSG.
I know what this is (it happens when the displacement is bigger than that allowed by the model or something like this) but I do not know how to solve this error (I know MASM is a 32 bit assembler and I am trying to write a 16 bit code). What I am trying to do is to load the pointer to .data into ds register.

My `makeit.bat` generated by the MASM32 IDE is:

```
@echo off
if exist "derivative 1.obj" del "derivative 1.obj" 
if exist "derivative 1.exe" del "derivative 1.exe" 
\masm32\bin\ml /c /coff "derivative 1.asm" 
if errorlevel 1 goto errasm 
\masm32\bin\PoLink /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE "derivative 1.obj" 
if errorlevel 1 goto errlink dir "derivative 1.*" goto TheEnd 
:errlink 
  echo _ 
  echo Link error 
  goto TheEnd 

:errasm 
  echo _ 
  echo Assembly Error 
  goto TheEnd 

:TheEnd 
  pause
```

Comment: Add also command line, how you invoke the MASM (will make bigger chance this will attract somebody with MASM knowledge to try it out). And you want to load into `ds` the `SEGMENT` part of address, not `OFFSET`. I.e. `mov ax, segment MSG` `mov ds,ax` `mov bx, offset MSG` => `ds:bx` contains complete segment:offset representation of the 20 bit physical memory address. Although from the error it looks like something more fundamental about your MASM setup is wrong, maybe treating that source as 32/64b, because what you wrote should compile in 16b, it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: There is no command line, i assemble it from MASM with makeit.bat(it is an IDE command)

Comment: `makeit.bat` is DOS batch file (similar to unix shell scripts). You can open it in text editor to see what commands are invoked and with which arguments. "from MASM" .. wait, MASM is just assembler, you can't be "in it", do you mean Visual Studio? Then you can still check with some flags which commands are invoked. I can't be specific, as I didn't see Microsoft products over 10 years, I'm already fully migrated to linux and other *NIX systems, where these things are simple to do (as long as you don't mind different assembly syntax, I personally prefer NASM). Posting versions may help...

Comment: yes I know I can edit a .bat file, I just copied it to C: and it does not let me edit it.

Comment: C:\>type makeit.bat
@echo off

    if exist "derivative 1.obj" del "derivative 1.obj"
    if exist "derivative 1.exe" del "derivative 1.exe"

    \masm32\bin\ml /c /coff "derivative 1.asm"
    if errorlevel 1 goto errasm

    \masm32\bin\PoLink /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE "derivative 1.obj"
    if errorlevel 1 goto errlink
    dir "derivative 1.*"
    goto TheEnd

  :errlink
    echo _
    echo Link error
    goto TheEnd

  :errasm
    echo _
    echo Assembly Error
    goto TheEnd

  :TheEnd

pause

Comment: Yes, thank you, I have to link it with link16 or use this program WinAsm  WinAsm is very simple and allows for 16 bit appications to be assembled fast

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *MASM32* package doesn't come with support for 16-bit executable generation, although it's not difficult to alter this behaviour. The *MASM* assembler in the *MASM32* package will generate 16-bit code but the linkers supplied will not generate 16-bit executables. This results in the type of error(s) you are seeing.

You can download a copy of an older linker that supports 16-bit targets. I've made [link16.exe](http://www.capp-sysware.com/downloads/link16.exe) (version 5.60.339 Dec 5 1994) available for download on my server.

Place `link16.exe` into the `\masm32\bin` directory. You will have to modify the generated `makeit.bat` file. The line that calls the linker (like `link.exe` or `polink.exe`) has to be replaced with:

```
\masm32\bin\link16.exe "filename.obj" ;
```

`filename.obj` is the name of the file you want to link. Change it to suit your project. The semicolon on the end will default all the file names and won't prompt for them. You will then have to modify the the `ml` line in `makeit.bat` so that it doesn't produce `coff` files. To do that remove `/coff` option:

```
\masm32\bin\ml /c "filename.asm"
```

Again `filename.asm` can be replaced by the name of the file in your project.

---

### Other Observations

Once you are able to generate a 16-bit executable some issues with your code:

- Remove `stack db  100 dup(?)` and use the `.stack` directive instead

  > ```
  > .stack 100h
  > ```
- You need to set up the segment value of `MSG` in *DS* instead:

  > ```
  > mov ax, seg MSG
  > mov ds, ax
  > ```

  With the `.small` model there is only one `data` segment. In the `.small` model `.data` and `.data?` will be combined into a single `.data` segment. With this memory model you can also initialize *DS* this way:

  > ```
  > mov ax, @data
  > mov ds, ax
  > ```
- For an DOS EXE program you'll need to exit with something like the [DOS exit interrupt](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2974.htm)

  > ```
  > mov ax, 4c00h
  > int 21h
  > ```

If you are using *MASM32* on a 64-bit version of Windows you wil not be able to directly run the 16-bit applications you create. You will have to download an emulator like [DOSBox](https://www.dosbox.com/) to run it, or install Virtual Machine (VMWare, VirtualBox, QEMU etc) software with a version of DOS/Windows that can run the code.

Answer (score 0):

For 16 bit assembly, with dot directives (like .model, .data, .code) the syntax is:

```
        mov     ax, @data
        mov     ds, ax
```

Comment: mov  ax, @data             I receive the error undefined symbol: DGROUP  someone says to play with the MODEL

Comment: Yeah, it works for 16 assembler. I'm looking into this.

Comment: The assembly error can be fixed in the batch file by using command line option /omf: `ml /c /omf example.asm`, but I'm not sure how to get 16 bit link output.

Comment: @ValentinBogatu - I could only get this to work with 16 bit linker. In my case, I have a full set of 16 build tools. You may be able to find and download a copy of the 16 bit tool set Visual C/C++ 1.52c. Visual C/C++ 1.52c is also included with the 32 bit tool set Visual C/C++ 4.1, but that will be harder to find.

Comment: I'll try to find an online 16 bit assembler. :)

Comment: @ValentinBogatu if you don't have some very strong reason why MASM (i.e. you plan to use MASM macros and quirk syntax, or you have some good book using MASM syntax), you can use NASM or FASM for windows (both have slightly different syntax, but reasonably close to MASM, and when they differ, they are usually closer to the original hazy Intel design used in Intel docs).

Comment: @ValentinBogatu - "16 bit assembler" - see if you can find a copy of MASM 6.11 (ML.EXE). It's a 16 bit assembler (also supports 32 bit assembly), but ML.EXE is a 32 bit program using a dos extender if running in real 16 bit MSDOS, or runs in a Windows 32 bit console window. It includes some other stuff like programmer's workbench (text base IDE), and codeview (text based source level debugger).

Answer (score 0):

To all that gave me answers to the simple question above I am saying Thank you. Indeed the answer to my question is that the link16.exe is necessary to generate the 16 bit code. 
Another way I could assemble simply and fast my code was using WinAsm wich is an older IDE that I found by googling.